# I wonder how to process events after logging in to Laravel auth

Tags: php

I am currently using an auth function. What I want to implement is to update the user's 'login_date' column to the current time when the user logs in. How do I curl up the LoginController in auth?

```
  protected $redirectTo = '/home';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Laravel 5 :

You can use built-in `authenticated()` method that are use in `AuthenticatesUsers` trait. Add following line of code on `app >> Http >> Controllers >> Auth >> LoginController`

```php
    /**
     * The user has been authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  mixed  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        // Add your business logic here
        $user->login_date = new \DateTime();
        $user->save();
    }
```

Make sure `login_date` to `$fillable` property in your `\App\User` class

Answer (score 0):

Not much to say I guess

```
/** @var \App\User $user */
$user = auth()->user();
$user->login_date = now();
$user->save();
```

or add `login_date` to `$fillable` property in your `\App\User` class and you can inline it too

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'email',
    'password',
    'login_date',
];
```

`auth()->user()->update(['login_date' => now()]);`

Comment: Where can I write this? There is no function because I am using auth.

Comment: What auth? laravel default auth ? if yes then you can use it anywhere that you can write php.